# How to use Jacoco and Junit Programmatically without Gradle/Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, junit, jupyter-notebook, code-coverage, jacoco

I need to use Jacoco and Junit on the fly with Jupyter and IJava kernel.
Do exist a programmatic way to use JaCoCo with Junit by passing the list of test classes to exec and the list of classes to compute the coverage?

I see [that codes](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api.html) that use the JaCoCo API and I test it with [this notebook](https://github.com/nicolalandro/java_junit_jupyter/blob/wip/notebooks/3-Jacoco.ipynb).
I try to expand it with Junit in [this other notebook](https://java-jupyter.herokuapp.com/notebooks/notebook/4-JacocoJunit.ipynb) but it seems do not work.

**Quick Replicate the problem**

- run with docker `docker run -v notebook:/server/notebook -p 8888:8888 nicolalandro/multilanguage-jupyter:1.0`
- (or if you prefer you can deploy the jupyter notebook on Heroku by clicking the Deploy button on [this Repo README.md](https://github.com/nicolalandro/java_junit_jupyter).)
- java download and open [this notebook](https://java-jupyter.herokuapp.com/notebooks/notebook/4-JacocoJunit.ipynb).